# How to validate input with non spaces in end of the input

Tags: .net-core

I want to validate my input string having numbers, spaces, and characters only. 
I did it, but I want another validation: the user shouldn't enter spaces at the end of the input. 
Can you please help me to resolve it?

> [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]{16}$")]

Comment: What about a simple `if(input[input.Length-1] == ' '){ // validation error }`. Easy to read, debug and maintain over time...

Comment: Thank you. can you add an answer. I can suggest it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about a simple

```
if(input[input.Length-1] == ' ')
{ 
   // validation error 
}
```

Easy to read, debug and maintain over time...